# How to reduce deployment size for Remix.js project?

Tags: node-modules, remix.run

I just created a Hello World project from this https://github.com/remix-run/remix/tree/main/templates/remix

And I deploy the project to Azure Web App using this GitHub Action

```yaml
name: Deploy to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: |
          zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'xxx'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: xxx
          package: .
```

When running this action, I noticed it packages the whole `node_modules`, thus producing a huge single file (500MB+), and uploading to Azure Web App is very long due to the large file size.

How to reduce the deployed file size?